# AngularJS : Child directive scope to inherit from parent directive isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If `a` and `b` are my directives such that `b` is a child element of `a` :

```
<a>
  <b></b>
</a>
```

Is it possible that if `a` has an isolated scope, then `b` could inherit from it?

Example js:

```
app.directive('a', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.prop1 = ...
    }
  }
});
app.directive('b', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      //how to access $scope.prop1 here?
    }
  }
});
```

With this, I'm trying to make directives that are reusable and are supposed to be used as nested within each other.

I know that I can `require` the controller of `a` on directive `b` to access it within the link function of `b` as one way to share the data between controllers, but that approach isn't working very well if I have more than one level of nesting.

Comment: could you add some code with plunkr..what you have tried and whats your issue?

Comment: @PankajParkar I want to be able to share data between nested directives (with more than one level of nesting), without polluting the non-directive scope.

Comment: <b> is in <a> scope already. Not clear what the problem is. Question is too vague without example

Comment: @charlietfl, not if `<a>` has `scope: {}` - then `b` wouldn't inherit from it

Comment: @NewDev understood...my point was the lack of clarity without trying to assume anything at all

Comment: @charlietfl if <a> has isolate scope, then b doesn't inherit from it

Comment: @charlietfl Ya dude, how could you not read his mind? /s

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha it sure works fine here where <b> is nested in <a > and <a> is isolated  http://plnkr.co/edit/DR4X4ylTnjOKYYMEBKoA?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev goes back to my point of lack of detail. Example acheives same structure and does work

Comment: @NewDev NO...the DOM structure is clearly defined. Question is not

Comment: and no reason it can't be interpreted either  way ... lack of clarity

Comment: Please see the EDIT 2, I have added some code which demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve. Hope that it clears any pending confusions up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you need to use the manual transclusion function. If the parent directive has an isolate scope, the child DOM elements (and their directives) would not inherit from it (only, if they were in its template).

When you transclude, you can specify the scope explicitly:

```
.directive("a", function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
       var newScope = scope.$new();
       transclude(newScope, function(clone){
         element.append(clone);
       })
    }
  };
});
```

You should note, though, that although the above would work (in the sense that the child directive's scope would inherit the parent's isolate scope), it is also a somewhat confusing experience to the user of your directive.

To see why, imagine that `a` exposes some `$innerProp` on its scope. The user of `a` now has to know that such property is "magically" available. This makes the HTML less readable without knowing a lot about `a`:

```
<a>
  <b item="$innerProp"></b>
</a>
```

**Addendum**

Depending on your use case, there might be other approaches that are more suitable. The above approach works better when `a` and `b` are independent, and when `a` uses its contents to allow its user to specify some template.

If `b` is only (or mostly) used as a child of `a`, then it should `require` it. `a` can expose whatever it needs via its controller API to `b`.

Lastly, if `a` has a well-defined structure, then it should use its `template` to specify `b`. In your example, this could easily be achieved with a template.

Comment: Why do I have to do a `item="$innerProp"` in <b> to capture the exposed property by <a>? Isn't <b> inheriting from <a> when we use `scope.$new()`?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, you don't *have to*. You could rely (although arguably, it's not the best practice) on magically having `scope.$innerProp` in the link function of `b` - it's there. But typically directives get their data explicitly via attributes. Also, you might need to use some other directive (e.g. `ng-if`) where you would have to use an attribute

Comment: that's not a problem since in my use case, the <b> is to be used within <a> and <a> definitely has to expose the `$innerProp`

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, then, I would recommend to use `require` instead due to tight-coupling between `b` and `a`. If `b` rarely (if ever) stands on its own, then this seems to be the better approach. Also, if `b` must always be inside `a`, then setting `b` in the template of `a` should also be considered

Comment: your solution seems to work. But I'm curious as to what's going on behind the scenes. Could you explain about the manual transclusion stuff or point me to some documentation that might?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, there is the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion), but in a nutshell, Angular takes the subtree, compiles it and gives you the transclusion function to manually link against some scope and place the content where needed